# HowTo change Mouse Cursors in all Windows and Applications?

Tags: unity, mouse, themes

I use Ubuntu Unity tool to change mouse cursors. But, now I have **three differents results**.

1) **In Firefox** I have the wanted result, my mouse cursor theme applied.

2) **In Ubuntu** I still have a white huge mouse cursor.

3) **The top bar** of all Ubuntu Windows I have the white huge cursor.

Long sentence short, is there a way to change my mouse cursor in Ubutu coherently, and homogenous for all and every application, position and window areas?

Answer (score 5):

#### 1. Open a terminal and enter

```
~$ sudo emacs /usr/share/icons/default/index.theme
```

Then, let's say your wanted cursor theme name is [PolarCursorTheme-Blue](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Polar+Cursor+Theme?content=27913), in that file change the `Inherits` property to:

`Inherits=PolarCursorTheme-Blue`

Save the file and exit emacs (or your favorite editor).

#### 2.  LogIn and LogOut

Now it works across all applications.

Can somebody from the Ubuntu dev team please implement a **automatic Mouse Switcher** into the very **core operating system**. This is a core feature everybody I asked, wants.